# Script that will read 5 numbers and then sort from highest to lowest

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort

I am trying to create a script that will get 5 numbers and then sort them from biggest to lowest.
So far, this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "********Sorting********"
echo "Enter first number:"
read n1
echo "Enter second number:"
read n2
echo "Enter third number:"
read n3
echo "Enter fourth number:"
read n4
echo "Enter fifth number:"
read n5
```

Comment: also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112600/4023950) on SO. for DESC sort use with `-rn`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just use sort with the reverse switch:

```
echo -e "$n1\n$n2\n$n3\n$n4\n$n5" | sort -rn
```

Comment: Careful to sort -n, so that 10 comes after 9, not before it.

Comment: or `printf '%s\n' "$n1" "$n2" "$n3" "$n4" "$n5" | sort -rn`.

Answer (score 3):

The better way to program this task.

```
#!/bin/bash

# put number names into array
number_names_arr=(first second third fourth fifth)

# use loop, because code duplication is a bad practice. 
# It repeats five times all commands it have inside.
for ((i = 0; i < 5; i++)); do
    # Prompt line
    echo "Enter ${number_names_arr[i]} number"

    # read inputted number into array
    read -r numbers_arr[i]
done

echo "Output:"
# pass the content of array to the sort command
printf '%s\n' "${numbers_arr[@]}" | sort -rn
```

Comment: Varaible `number` is not necessary as you can read directly into an array element. You can also prompt with `read -p`. The loop body can thus sum up to `read -p "Enter ${number_names_arr[i]} number"$'\n' -r numbers_arr[i]`

Comment: @xhienne Thanks, I changed the code. I was suspected, that the `read` can store straight into the array element, but couldn't did this (didn't know how pass array to the `read`) and decided use the additional variable `number`. But I still left prompt string on the separate line for readability.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=("${@}")

while [[ "${1++}" ]]; do
  n=${1}
  <<< "${n}" grep -P -e '^(([+-]?)([0-9]+?)(\.?)(([0-9]+?)?))$' > '/dev/null' \
    || { echo "ERROR: '${n}' is not a number"; exit 1; }
  shift
done

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | sort -rg
```

Example:

```
$ myscript.sh 12 -45 2 -27.75 2.2 0 +25 100 2.15
100
+25
12
2.2
2.15
2
0
-27.75
-45
```

Comment: 0 is not a number? Apart from that, this seems unnecessarily complicated: if you can call a script with N numbers in parameters, then you can just execute `printf '%s\n' 824 260 24 100 841 | sort -rn`. What does your code bring with respect to other answers?

Comment: I've fixed it. Thanks for telling me. I thought that this could be easier to implement in other scripts, but guess I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but your fix `((n == n))` is equivalent to `true`, this is not the way to test if n is a number. The other problem that makes your code complicated is that you mimics arrays whereas `bash` has real indexed arrays; why not just use them instead? (see MiniMax answer, here you would do `array=("$@")`). If you don't want to use arrays, it would be much more interesting if you provided a full POSIX-compliant `sh` code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, I really appreciate it. I've edited my answer again, do you think that could be a better approach?

It accepts negative numbers (and the redundant-but-not-incorrect representation of positive numbers) and even decimal numbers.

Comment: That's better. The while loop is still more complicated than necessary. `${i++}` adds nothing to a mere `$i` in this context, and the `while [ "$1" ]; do n=$1; ...; shift; done` can be advantageously substituted with a simpler `for n; do ...; done`. And since you don't use the array in your loop, drop the array and use `"$@"` in your last line. That said, you are new here, you ought to know that what really matters is answering to the OP and in that respect, then only interesting part is that last line. +1 for using `sort -g`.